How can I remove the project/module name embedded in the Go executable?
I'm new to Go and I'm working on a project and using go mod init PROJECTNAME to set up my module. When I build the project with go build, the executable generated includes the project/module name (PROJECTNAME) that I specified during go mod init. Could be found using findstr "PROJECTNAME" output.exe
I want to build the executable without embedding the project/module name inside it. Is there a way to prevent Go from embedding the module name, or a way to set a custom module name in the compiled binary?
Any help or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Did you try ldflags? To Strip debug Infos

yes I tried -ldflags="-s -w"
